# Display leading zeros in PHP

Tags: php, html

I've created this column on my DB named `trackingcode`, it has the `UNSIGNED ZEROFILL` attribute so it would show the leading zeros in the DB. See below example.

[image]

Now I would send these tracking codes through email (PHP form to email). The problem is that on the email, it would only show the whole number but not the zero.

[image]

Is there a way to make the leading zeros show up in the email subject?

```js
$email_subject = "PC Request # $newtracking";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if these values are stored as strings in your database, but either way you can fudge it with this

```
$val = substr("00" . $newtracking, -3);
```

Comment: ... or use `str_pad` ... ? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

Comment: Thanks guys! `str_pad` works fine too!